# How do I interpret the definition of a distribution in this book by Joshi & Friedlander?

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory

I was wondering about the following definition in the book Introduction to the Theory of Distributions, by Joshi and Friedlander:
[image]

In the Appendix the bracket operation is defined as
[image]

To me this definition of a distribution doesn't make sense if we view the bracket operation as an inner product, e.g., an integral, since the domain of $u$ is $C_c^\infty(X)$ whereas the domain of $\phi$ is $X$. So then how do we make sense of $\int u(x)\phi(x) dx$?

I would understand if $u$ were, say, a continuous function from $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Then $u$ would *determine* a linear form through $\langle u, \phi \rangle$. Is that what the definition means? We take some object $u$, then $u$ determines a linear form through the pairing $\langle u, \phi \rangle$? And then we refer to $u$ as a linear form because somehow the linear form determines $u$ uniquely? Perhaps this bit from the book is relevant:

[image]

Comment: $ \langle u, \phi \rangle$ is just a notation for  the value of $u$ at $\phi$. No inner product is involved here.

Comment: You seem to be assuming that every linear form on $C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ comes from a function. But there are other forms, and those are called distributions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation $\langle u,\varphi\rangle$ is just a fancy way of writing $u(\varphi)$ for a linear from $u\colon C^\infty_c(X)\to\mathbb{C}$. Examples of linear forms which are not defined by functions are $\delta_0$ or $\partial^\alpha\delta_0$ which are defined as
$$
\langle \delta_0, \varphi\rangle = \varphi(0) \qquad \text{and}\qquad \langle \partial^\alpha\delta_0, \varphi\rangle = (-1)^{|\alpha|}(\partial^\alpha\varphi)(0).
$$
For these two it is easy to check that they satisfy the condition stated above. A slightly more complicated example might be
$$
\langle \mathrm{vp}\frac{1}{x}, \varphi\rangle = \lim_{\varepsilon\to 0} \int_{\mathbb{R}\setminus(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)} \frac{\varphi(x)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x.
$$
Note that none of these distributions can be represented by a continuous function.